# SharePoint 2013/16 Doc Library web part - change view but no new page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have a requirement to change the view in the Document Libarary web part, and I already have the change view links enabled. They do not want the view to open in a new page, but to change the view within the web part itself? Any idea on how to do this?
Thank you
Doug

Comment: They just want to change the default view or create new view and keep default view as it is?

Comment: They want to switch view that are already created, but stay within the webpart not open a new page

Answer (score 0):

To switch view that are already created for a document library web part, you don't need to open a new page.

Just edit the page, edit the web part, then switch view from the web part:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! i should explain better, they want to click a new view inside the webpart and have the new view render inside the webpart instead of being bumped out into a new page (the library)

Comment: I am not very understanding of you, when i click a new view inside the web part and the new view render inside the web part, it doesn't bumped out into a new page (the library).

Comment: Hi Lisa. Ok I will add a couple screens to the post. When i click a view link inside the web part (not web part properties) it opens in a new browser tab. Client want to the view to just change in the webpart itself